# What are the procedures/"tricks" to brake bleeding a Ferrari 575?

Tags: brakes

What is the procedure/"tricks" to bleed the brakes on a 2002 Ferrari 575?

Comment: What are your worries?

Answer (score 5):

Ferrari use an analyser, SD2 or SD3, which has a procedure programmed into it for bleeding the brakes. The machine should be considered essential to do a proper job, and uses the ABS pump to fully flush, vacate and refill the braking system.